# What does "hope you're not 2-timing me" mean?

Tags: meaning

> I hope you're not 2-timing me

I know this is grammatically incorrect, but I would like to understand what this means. One of my friends commented this, and I don't know what it means no matter how hard I try.

Comment: It is text-speak for [**two-timing**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/two-time). Your friend wants to know if you are dating anyone else.

Comment: Although it literally means being romantically involved with more than one person, it could be used in a figurative joking sense to mean "spending time with another friend instead of me and lying about it."

Comment: You really don't know the meaning? That is rather a puzzling puzzle ...

Comment: @CanadianYankee Or in a business sense, contracting a competitor of the business in question as well.

Answer (score 7):

> “hope your not 2 timing me”

Let's correct the grammar first.

*I hope **you're** not two-timing me.*

> Definition of two-time transitive verb
>
> 1: to betray (a spouse or lover) by secret lovemaking with another
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-time

Comment: Yikes! I doubt the OP's friend was accusing someone of infidelity. I've only ever heard "two-timing" used to mean "double-cross" (i.e., "betray" without the sexual connotation), which is Webster's definition #2. It's probably better to include both definitions, and let the OP decided which is applicable.